# SQL Query for finding Nth max sal of employee group by deptno

Tags: sql

```
select deptno,distinct(sal) from emp e1
group by deptno,sal
where 3=(select count(distinct(sal)) from emp e2 where e1.sal<=e2.sal);
```

I have got error**"missing expression"**

Comment: Your query seems to be wrong.post your input table and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

`Group By` comes after the `where`-Clause:

```
select deptno, distinct(sal)
from emp e1
where 3 = (select count(distinct(sal)) from emp e2 where e1.sal<=e2.sal)
group by deptno,sal;
```

And I'm not entirely sure if the sub select really does what you want it to do, but I have no way of testing it right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is invalid.
The correct sql `GROUP BY`'s syntax is

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name;
```

Group by should be last.
More info : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp